# Link events (birthdays/anniversaries) from Google Contacts to Google Calendar in Android

Tags: contacts, calendar, google-calendar, google-contacts

In my contacts app, I have birthdays and anniversaries saved for most contacts. On most birthdays, I get a reminder 3 days before and then on the day of the birthday at 10 am. I have not created this setting but I'm good as long as I get a notification - so no complaints here.

However, for some birthdays and all anniversaries, nothing like this happens. I get no notifications whatsoever.
When I tap on a contact's anniversary, I am redirected to the calendar app where I can see an event for that contact's anniversary in the year that anniversary first occurred. However, for subsequent years, no such event is there. This same problem also happens for some birthdays. This is only happening in the Calendar app on Android. On opening the Google Calendar in a browser tab on my laptop, I can all birthdays and anniversaries populating properly.

So my question is: What do I have to do so that such missing events are populated on Google Calendar so I can get a notification on my Android phone?

Comment: Is this the Contacts app that came pre-installed on your device? If yes what Android phone (model name and manufacturer + Android version) do you use? If it is a different Contacts app please provide link to Play Store page of the app.

Comment: There was a brand-new announcement for the Contacts app that may make this easier to solve: https://9to5google.com/2023/03/17/google-contacts-birthday-notification/

Comment: @jlehenbauer manually enabling notifications for all contacts will be a chore and this doesn't mention anything about anniversaries. But this update could be a partial solution at least - thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Robert Yes this is the standard Google Contacts app which was preinstalled on my phone. I am using Redmi Note 11 Pro+ 5G (2201116SI) by Xiaomi running Android 12 SKQ1.211006.001